# Python Regular Expressions to extract date

Tags: python, regex

I have strings that look like these:

```
{server}_{date:YYYYMMDD}{int:######}
{server}_{date:MON DAY YYYY}{int:######}
```

...plus more, in different date formats.  Also, there can be any number of {} blocks, and they can appear in any order.

I'm trying to get just the "date" part between the curly braces in Python 3.2.  So for the first string, I want to get just "{date:YYYYMMDD}" and for the second string I want just "{date:MON DAY YYYY}".  The only characters I want inside the "date" block are alpha and whitespace.

My regex pattern is:

```
\{date:(\w|\s)*\}
```

I've tested this out on [this Regex builder](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), but it's not matching as expected.  This is my output on Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\{date:(\w|\s)*\}', '{server}_{date:YYYYMMDD}{date:MONDAYYYYY}{int:######}')
['D', 'Y']
>>> re.findall('\{date:(\w|\s)*\}', '{server}_{date:MON DAY YYYY}{int:######}')
['Y']
```

Can someone please point out what's wrong with my pattern?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!  Looking at everyone's answers now, it's obvious I left out important details in my question.  I edited my post and added some more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'(\{date:[\w\s]+\})'` gives what you want:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('(\{date:[\w\s]+\})', '{server}_{date:YYYYMMDD}{date:MONDAYYYYY}{int:######}')
['{date:YYYYMMDD}', '{date:MONDAYYYYY}']
>>> re.findall('(\{date:[\w\s]+\})', '{server}_{date:MON DAY YYYY}{int:######}')
['{date:MON DAY YYYY}']
```

If you want only data value, use `'\{date:([\w\s]+)\}'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.findall('\{date:([\w\s]*)\}', '{server}_{date:YYYYMMDD}{date:MONDAYYYYY}{int:######}')
['YYYYMMDD', 'MONDAYYYYY']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
str = '{server}_{date:MON DAY YYYY}{int:######}'
re.findall('\{date:.*\}(?=\{)',str)
```

it returns this

> ```
> ['{date:MON DAY YYYY}']
> ```

and

```
str = '{server}_{date:YYYYMMDD}{int:######}'
re.findall('\{date:.*\}(?=\{)',str)
```

returns the following:

> ['{date:YYYYMMDD}']

the `(?=..\{)` does the following:

> (?=...)
>   Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For >example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.[(source)](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

*note:* this will only function if another block {..} following {date}, I assume this is necessary, and if it is missing your input may be invalid.

Comment: I should have mentioned that there can be any number of {} blocks, and they can appear in any order.  My bad, my question was not detailed enough.  I appreciate the answer though.

Comment: well, this will still find the block that begins with `{date:.*]` so long as another block follows it.

Answer (score 0):

```
'{server}_({date:.+?}){int:'
```

enough

.

or , may be better

```
'(?<={server}_)({date:.+?})(?={int:)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a capturing group around the entire regex, and a non-capturing group for the `(\w|\s)` part:

`(\{date:(?:\w|\s)*\})`

That will result in the output you want:

```
>>> re.findall('(\{date:(?:\w|\s)*\})', '{server}_{date:MON DAY YYYY}{int:######}')
['{date:MON DAY YYYY}']
>>> re.findall('(\{date:(?:\w|\s)*\})', '{server}_{date:YYYYMMDD}{date:MONDAYYYYY}{int:######}')
['{date:YYYYMMDD}', '{date:MONDAYYYYY}']
```

Comment: It's not actually necessary to place parenthesis around the whole regex if you use a non-capturing group. `'\{date:(?:\w|\s)*\}'` generates the same result.